# ActiveX check box to hide rows between two rows with specific text

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I want to use a check box to hide all rows between two rows that have the text "XXX" and "YYY". First I am defining and setting public ranges to the cells containing the text with this Sub:

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

Public D1 As Range, D2 As Range
Set D1 = Sheet3.Columns("A").Find(what:="XXX", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set D2 = Sheet3.Columns("A").Find(what:="YYY", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

End Sub
```

I then set up the activeX check box like this:

```
Private Sub Check_Click()

If Check = True Then
Sheet3.Rows(D1.Row + 1 & ":" & D2.Row - 2).Hidden = False
Else:
Sheet3.Rows(D1.Row + 1 & ":" & D2.Row - 2).Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

However, I keep getting the following error: Object required. Am I declaring the Ranges wrong? How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `Am I declaring the Ranges wrong` Yes. Move them from `Workbook_Open()` to `Check_Click()` and also check if `D1` and `D2` are valid ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comments below your post, try something like this (**UNTESTED**)

```
Private Sub Check_Click()
    Dim D1 As Range, D2 As Range

    With Sheet3
        Set D1 = .Columns(1).Find(what:="XXX", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set D2 = .Columns(1).Find(what:="YYY", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If D1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If D2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        If Check = True Then
            .Rows(D1.Row + 1 & ":" & D2.Row - 2).Hidden = False
        Else
            .Rows(D1.Row + 1 & ":" & D2.Row - 2).Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I am assuming the following

1. You are using an ActiveX Checkbox called `Check`
2. You have a sheet which has a codename `Sheet3`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, while the code you provided works for hiding the rows, it is not working for unhding. Any clue as to why? Thanks again.

Comment: It hides the rows upon a click when the check box is unchecked, but it doesn't unhide them when I click on the check box again to unhide them.

Comment: So it is sorted I guess?

Comment: Almost. I am trying to have the same check box control rows on a different sheet. I did the same code but "With Sheet2", but nothing happens. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Step through the code and check :) Check if both values are there in col 1 of sheet2